# Why don’t GPIO lines work for DS18B20 Sensor?

Tags: gpio, ds18b20

Recently, I bought a DS18B20 temp sensor to monitor my fermentation temp of my beer and assumed I could just hook up the power, ground and data to their respective pins on the Pi but I could never get it to work. I looked online and there were a lot of tutorials that suggest the modprobe terminal approach but very few (if any) that gave a straightforward GPIO.setup, GPIO.input approach. Is there a reason for this? Is the Dallas 1-wire protocol more complex than I’m assuming? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Which are "their respective pins on the Pi" and what did you do to "get it to work"?

Comment: Have you enabled the right device tree overlay `dtoverlay=w1-gpio` or `dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup`  in /boot/config.txt?  https://pinout.xyz/pinout/1_wire

Comment: These two posts might help: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/pi-cant-find-5th-ds18b20
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102078/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-rj-x.

Comment: @Dougie this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable 1-wire (with or without parasitic power) you need

`dtoverlay=w1-gpio`

`dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup`

in /boot/config.txt