# W1 works on one pi but not the other

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, ds18b20

I have recently purchased a Raspberry Pi Zero w and soldered the GPIO pins. I set up a DS18B20 and everything worked fine. I used some other pins as inputs and went back to check the sensor but the pi couldn't detect it. I doubled checked with another pi (3B), using the same SD card and sensor layout and it could be detected.

I've followed all other guides for setting up the DS18B20; changing the /boot/config.txt file, double checking the layout, setting the w1 to gpio4, but nothing seems to work.

I guess I am just confused why it works on my 3B pi but not my pi zero. 
Any suggestions?

My only thought is that I might have messed up the GPIO pins on my zero while trying to use some as inputs.

It should also be noted that I can use the pins as outputs just fine. I have a 7-segment display hooked up and it can run through all the numbers. Also I can see devices under /sys/bus/w1/devices but they all start with 00-* so I know none of these are the temperature sensor. Again the same setup works on a different pi and was originally working on my zero. I also tried other pins for the data input on the zero with no luck.
Thanks for the help!

UPDATE: It appears that my pin7 is no longer responsive. I tried all the tests with pigpio and they all passed, however after trying with a voltage meter I can see that pin 7 does not respond. I tried the thermometer with another pin and changed the /boot/config.txt to include the pin I wanted w1 to use and it worked fine.
Might've accidentally shorted it with 5v while trying input? Not exactly sure but glad I can see the sensor again.

Comment: Download [gpiotest](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/gpiotest.zip), `sudo pigpiod`, then `./gpiotest`.  See [here](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing) for details.

Comment: @Jade_Tempest, I am not surprised.  I have found a couple of various other device drivers working on Rpi3B+ but not on RpiZ/W.  Perhaps you can try your luck on  python3-w1ThermSensor-1.0.5 (I have not tried the newer v1.1)
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/pi-cant-find-5th-ds18b20/100244#100244.

Comment: But have you tried more than one GPIO pin on your RpiZ?  It is a good idea to try the I2C pins which has strong pullups.  RpiZ might be weaker than it big bother Rpi3 to pull down things. (see my answer referred above).